# Pass Type as parameter and check

Tags: c#, asp.net, types

I want to build a method that accepts parameter as `Type` like

```
void M1(Type t)
{
  // check which type it is
}
```

and call it like

```
M1(typeof(int));
```

I have no idea how to check `type` in method body.

I have tried

```
if (t is double)
```

But it is giving warning

```
The given expression never provided type (double)
```

Please help me for checking the type of parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to check for an *exact* type, you can use:

```
if (t == typeof(double))
```

That's fine for `double`, given that it's a struct, so can't be inherited from.

If you want to perform a more is-like check - e.g. to check whether a type is compatible with `System.IO.Stream` - you can use [`Type.IsAssignableFrom`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom):

```
if (typeof(Stream).IsAssignableFrom(t))
```

That will match if `t` is `System.IO.MemoryStream`, for example (or if it's `System.IO.Stream` itself).

I always find myself having to think slightly carefully to work out which way round the call goes, but the target of the call is *usually* a `typeof` expression.

Comment: @ImadoddinIbnAlauddin: That was an example where you might want to use inheritance - to spot that the System.IO.Stream type is assignable from System.IO.MemoryStream, for example.

Answer (score 3):

You can try

```
  if(t == typeof(double))
```

or

```
 if (typeof(double).IsAssignableFrom(t))
```

or

```
 if(t == default(double).GetType())
```

or

```
 if(t.Name == "Double")
```

Personally i prefer the first option

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [IsAssignableFrom](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom(v=vs.110).aspx), which determines whether an instance of a specified type can be assigned to the current type instance.

```
public void M<T>(T value) 
{
    if (typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(double)))
        Console.Write("It's a double");  
}
```

It returns true if the given parameter:

- represents the same type.
- is derived either directly or indirectly from the current instance.
- is a generic type parameter, and the current instance represents one of the constraints of the parameter.
- represents a value type, and the current instance represents Nullable (Nullable(Of paramerter) in Visual Basic).